# How to change one character in excel from previous cell

Tags: .net, excel, excel-formula

i have records as follows

[image: my question]

I need to do auto increment for only last two digits in the email (in B column)

output should be as follows

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about : in B2

```
"support."&if(a2<10,"0"&A2,A2)&"@gmail.com"
```

Then drag down, now tested ...

Answer (score 1):

enter this formula in B2 cell and drag it down

```
="support."&TEXT(A2;"0#")&"@gmail.com"
```